# Is there any problem in performance if I use 'categorical_crossentropy' as loss function just to classify to objects?

Tags: tensorflow

I'm training a CNN to classify dogs and cats and I'm using 'categorical_crossentropy' as loss function because at beginning I had three classes, but at the end I decided to use just two, and I didn't have the opportunity to change the loss function.
My prolem here is that I don't have the computer where I was workinng to prove with 'binary_crossentropy'and I need to solve this quetion. So I don't know if it would have the same performance.

Here the part where I compile

```
model.compile(optimizer = keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=lr),
          loss='categorical_crossentropy',
          metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Comment: this question or answer  ???

Answer (score 0):

The answer is no, it is not a problem.

You can use `binary_crossentropy + Dense(1,activation='sigmoid')` or `categorical_crossentropy + Dense(2,activation='softmax')`.

The performance of your model should not be affected at all.